# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version spec

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I have a problem in build.gradle (Module app) that I can not resolve

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ahmedchtn.smartschool"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //RecyclerView

    //retrofit,gson

    //glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    //Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:25.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    //Firebase UI
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error is shown in this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Error message:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).Found versions 25.3.1,23.4.0.Examples include
com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and
com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` to avoid conflict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 0):

Use same version to all dependencies of support libraries. In your case change these dependency version to "25.3.1".

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: The error has disappeared from the line that I have said but for now the error is on this line :
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Comment: @AhmedKamel its not error you can still run your project.

Comment: @AhmedKamel  Have you declare the Google maven repo in `build.gradle`? `repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}`

Comment: Yeah I have add it but nothing happens